# Refactor this function to use "return" consistently inside and outside of if statement Javascript

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, return

I have a function where it sonar report that it does not use return consistently:

```
function getRate(a) {
  try {
    const manager = rateManagement.getInstance();
    const rate = await manager.getAllRate();
    let result = 0;

    if (rate && rate.length) {
      const rateConfig = rate.find((x) => x.rate?.includes(a));
      const aRating = rateConfig?.rate;

      result = aRating || result;
    }

    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    logger.logError(error);
  }
}
```

However, with this function, sonar did not detect it use return inconsistently even though I did not return anything inside the if as well:

```
 getGroup() {
  const manager = groupManagement.getInstance();
  const group = await manager.getAllGroup();

  let result = [];

  if (group && group.length) {
    result = group.map((x) => x.rate);
  }

  return result;
}
```

Is it because of the try, catch block? Can you please explain to me why?

Comment: What do you think will be returned from your function if an error is thrown inside the `try` block?

Comment: Oh I understand now. Thanks @Ivar

Comment: What is a common return inside a catch error block, return null? @Ivar

Comment: That depends a bit on if that is something to be expected when the function is called. If you return `null`, but the calling code doesn't take that into consideration, it will very likely cause errors down the line. If there isn't a logical value to be returned, it might be a strong indication that the error handling should be somewhere else down the line instead of in this function. It all depends on what should be happening if your code fails to get the rate.

Answer (score 0):

Function `getRate` does not return a value if an error is thrown inside the try-block, because the catch-block only logs the error, but does not return a value. You can "fix" this issue by returning some value, e.g., `undefined`. However, it typically makes more sense to throw the error and let the caller handle it.